# Separate html string using componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: html, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

I am getting the following html response from server.

```
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="text">
        test data 
    </td>
</tr>
```

From this I want to get "test data" string only. I am using "`componentsSeparatedByString`" to get the string . But its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far?  All you have to do is store each line in an array and look for the index of the element that contains '<td id="text">,' right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<td id="text">([0-9 A-z]+)</td>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&err];

NSString *string = @"</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td id="text">test data</td></tr>";

NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedString.length)];
NSString *result = nil;

if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    result = [string substringWithRange:range];
```